# Angular JS: How to apply the date range filter between two dates in one column

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am aware that it may be Duplicate Question, but I tried that too but it didnt work it. So, I am posting my Question now. My Question is Apply the Date range filter using Angular js only one column.
Here is MY code:

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<div>
<table>
<tr>
<td>Start Date</td>
<td><input type="text" name="S_Date" ng-model="startDate"/></td>
<td>End Date</td>
<td><input type="text" name="E_Date" ng-model="endDate"/>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
<table>
       <tr>
        <th>Date</th>.
        <th>Stock</th>
       </tr>
       <tr ng-repeat="subject in records |myfilter:startDate:endDate">
         <td>{{ subject.name * 1000|date:'dd-MM-yyyy'}}<td>
         <td>{{ subject.marks }}</td>
       </tr>

 </table>
```

Angular JS:

```
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
           $scope.records = [
           {
                "name" : "2016-08-01",
                "marks" : 250
            },{
                "name" : "2016-08-02",
                "marks" : 150
            },{
                "name" : "2016-08-03",
                "marks" : 100
            },{
                "name" : "2016-08-04",
                "marks" : 150
            },{
                "name" : "2016-05-01",
                "marks" : 750
            },{
                "name" : "2016-05-02",
                "marks" : 1500
            },{
                "name" : "2016-03-03",
                "marks" : 500
            },{
                "name" : "2016-04-04",
                "marks" : 650
            }
        ]


         function parseDate(input) {
      var parts = input.split('-');
      return new Date(parts[2], parts[1]-1, parts[0]); 
    }   
    app.filter("myfilter", function() {
      return function(items, from1, to) {

        var df = parseDate(from1);
            var dt = parseDate(to);
            alert(df)
            alert(dt)
            var result = [];        
            for (var i=0; i<items.length; i++){
                var tf = new Date(items[i].startDate * 1000),
                    tt = new Date(items[i].endDate * 1000);
                if (tf > df && tt < dt)  {
                    result.push(items[i]);
                }
            }            
            return result;
      };
    });
    });
    </script>
```

Please advice me Where I am going wrong.Please suggest me.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend you to use moment.js library: http://momentjs.com/

Here is working plunkr with your range filter: https://plnkr.co/edit/dfpsBI0uom5ZAEnDF3wM?p=info

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Start Date</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="S_Date" ng-model="startDate" />
    </td>
    <td>End Date</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="E_Date" ng-model="endDate" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Date</th>.
    <th>Stock</th>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="subject in records | myfilter: startDate: endDate">
    <td>{{ subject.name | date:'dd-MM-yyyy'}}</td>
    <td>{{ subject.marks }}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>



app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.startDate = "2016-08-01";
    $scope.endDate = "2016-08-03";
    $scope.records = [{
    "name": "2016-08-01",
    "marks": 250
    }, {
    "name": "2016-08-02",
    "marks": 150
    }, {
    "name": "2016-08-03",
    "marks": 100
    }, {
    "name": "2016-08-04",
    "marks": 150
    }, {
    "name": "2016-05-01",
    "marks": 750
    }, {
    "name": "2016-05-02",
    "marks": 1500
    }, {
    "name": "2016-03-03",
    "marks": 500
    }, {
    "name": "2016-04-04",
    "marks": 650
    }];
   });

   app.filter("myfilter", function($filter) {
    return function(items, from, to) {
     return $filter('filter')(items, "name", function(v) {
      var date = moment(v);
      return date >= moment(from) && date <= moment(to);
     });
    };
   });
```

Comment: Thanks.But I think Your plunkr is not working.Its showing something different.

Comment: Please, try it again

Comment: Thanks a lot.You saved me.

Comment: Hi Roman Koliada, I did some changes in you plunkr to enable datepicker selection. https://plnkr.co/edit/qgLfqi?p=info . This can be useful to another cases.

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.Customfilterobj`enter code here`  = { status: "Complete",StartDate: "2017-02-01T08:00:00",EndDate: "2018-02-01T08:00:00 " };


<tr ng-repeat="dt in data | filter: {Status: Customfilterobj.status} | dateRange:Customfilterobj.StartDate:Customfilterobj.EndDate">
```

Here we have use two filters as below:

`filter: {Status: Customfilterobj.status}` work as compare "complete" value with Status of data collection.

`dateRange:Customfilterobj.StartScheuleDate:Customfilterobj.EndScheuleDate"` : dateRange is custom filter for compare Expiration_date between StartDate and EndDate.

```
app.filter('dateRange', function () {
            return function (data, greaterThan, lowerThan) {
                 if (greaterThan != null && lowerThan != null && greaterThan != undefined && lowerThan != undefined) {
                    data = data.filter(function (item) {
                        if (item.Expiration_date != null) {
                           var exDate = new Date(item.Expiration_date);
                           return exDate >= new Date(greaterThan) && exDate <= new Date(lowerThan);
                        }
                    });
                }
                return data;
            };
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding off of [Roman Koliada's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37672084/3670393) plunker. His process has a small issue in the usage of the angular $filter. I have the updated here:

https://plnkr.co/edit/l4t4Fln4HhmZupbmOFki?p=preview

New filter:

```
 app.filter("myfilter", function($filter) {
  return function(items, from, to, dateField) {
    startDate = moment(from);
    endDate = moment(to);
    return $filter('filter')(items, function(elem) {
      var date = moment(elem[dateField]);
      return date >= startDate && date <= endDate;
   });
  };
});
```

The issue was that the function input into $filter function was the third param, and loops over every attribute of every object in the list. Console logging his plunker calls moment() on every single attribute of every object. By instead inputting a function as the second param, as the expression instead of the comparator - we can call the comparison only on the date field.

Angular doc: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter